# php and mysql function snowballing results

Tags: php, mysql

Im using the following function.

```
function GetSubmissions($coach){
     $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ptable` WHERE coach = '$_SESSION[username]'") or trigger_error(mysql_error()); 
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
     foreach($row AS $key => $value) { $row[$key] = stripslashes($value); } 
      $id = $row['id'];
      $teampre = $row['team'];
      $eventpre = $row['event'];
      $statuspre = $row['status'];
      $eventarray = DecodeEvent($eventpre);
       $event = $eventarray[0];
       $cat = $eventarray[1];
       $subcat = $eventarray[2];
       $division = $eventarray[3];
       $type = $eventarray[4];
      $teamarray = DecodeTeam($teampre);
        foreach ($teamarray AS $key => $value){
         $teamgo .= $value[1]." ".$value[2]."<br/>";
       } 
      $push .= "<div id=submission><div id=event>$event</div><div id=status>$statuspre</div><div id=subinfo>$cat $subcat $division $type</div><div id=team>$teamgo</div></div>";
     }   

  return $push;
 }
```

What is happening, is that the **$teampre** contains a series of numbers representing the team members, which i pass to the **DecodeTeam** function to return the names of the given members in an array. The problem is. That say there are 3 results for the main query. The first is fine. The second result starts off with the team members from the first result. The third result starts off with the team members from the first and second queries, like a snowball effect.

I figure the problem is in the way im handling the **$teamgo** variable, but im not sure how to get the results to stop snowballing like this.

Comment: Can you also include code for DecodeTeam?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just need to reset the `$teamgo` string each time you go through the loop:

```
$teamarray = DecodeTeam($teampre);
$teamgo = ""; // Reset so it doesn't contain the results from the last row.
foreach ($teamarray AS $key => $value){
   $teamgo .= $value[1]." ".$value[2]."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: If there was a high five button, i would have clicked that too! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I was beat to the bunch but I beautified your code =)

```
function GetSubmissions($coach) {

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ptable` WHERE coach = '$_SESSION[username]'");

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

    // stripslashes
    foreach($row AS $key => $value) { 
      $row[$key] = stripslashes($value); 
    } 

    $id         = $row['id'];
    $teampre    = $row['team'];
    $eventpre   = $row['event'];
    $statuspre  = $row['status'];

    $eventarray = DecodeEvent($eventpre);
    $event      = $eventarray[0];
    $cat        = $eventarray[1];
    $subcat     = $eventarray[2];
    $division   = $eventarray[3];
    $type       = $eventarray[4];

    $teamarray  = DecodeTeam($teampre);
    $teamgo     = '';
    foreach ($teamarray AS $key => $value) {
      $teamgo .= $value[1]." ".$value[2]."<br/>";
    } 

    $push .= "blah blah blah";

  }   

  return $push;

}
```